# The countdown timer goes to negative

Tags: react-hooks, use-effect

My countdown timer won’t stop after 0 and it went to negative even after I clear the interval. I seem not able to see where it went wrong.

Also after the timer goes to 0, I want the page automatically go to the next page without giving specific route, so I’m thinking using  useHistory and goForward() but don’t know where I add the hook in this function. Can I return clearInterval and history.goForward() both?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Timer = () => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(10);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(
      () => setSeconds((prevTimer) => prevTimer - 1),
      1000,
    );
    if (seconds === 0) {
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, []);

  return <div className="countdown">{seconds}</div>;
};

export default Timer;
```

Comment: Share code please...

Comment: sorry, I uploaded the image but didn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `useEffect` function is only called once on first render and never again. So you don't actually clear the interval. `clearInterval` needs to sit outside of that function so that it can be called when the seconds reach zero. I would write your code like so:

```
export default function App() {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = React.useState(10);
  const interval = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    interval.current = setInterval(
      () => setSeconds((prevTimer) => prevTimer - 1),
      1000
    );
  }, []);

  if (seconds === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval.current);
  }

  return <div className="countdown">{seconds}</div>;
}
```

> [useRef is like a “box” that can hold a mutable value in its .current property.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

So here you assign the interval to it and can clear it any time you want.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-sun-qizp7?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks, your code works! For useHistory, can I add this line after clearInterval(interval.current)?

Comment: history.goForward("/games/:gameName/tasks/:number/page/:number");

Comment: I reuse this component for other games that has different routes, so I wonder if I can use this hook to have it go to the next page with such a route pattern.

Comment: @coderonpointe It's hard to say without seeing the fuller context of the app, but usually `goForward` is used to simulate the forward button of the browser. You would typically use `push` to navigate to a specific page. of course, that will only work if you're within the context of your router and your history can see all those URL params e.g. `:gameName`. But generally speaking, yes, that's where you would put a redirect. To test, you can just put this after `clearInterval`: `window.location.replace("YOURURLHERE");`

Answer (score 0):

when you set timer inside useEffect  it's not aware of changes. I have updated your code. [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-water-g2lgr?file=/src/App.js:76-680)

```
export default function App() {
  let [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(15),
    [timer, setTimer] = useState(null); // IN YOU NEED TO STOP TIMER

  useEffect(() => {
    if (seconds > 0) updateSeconds();
    else {
      // go to next page
      // set timer
      // setSeconds(15);
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [seconds]);

  /* Timer Logic */
  function updateSeconds() {
    let timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
      setSeconds(seconds - 1);
    }, 1000);

    setTimer(timeOut);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello Timer</h1>
      <h2>{seconds}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It goes down but the timer cycles back from 15 again without clearing it.

Comment: That's how I coded it. Removed setSeconds in Else.

Comment: This timer works, thanks! As far as the logic for moving to the next page after timer is 0, can I use useHistory without specific path? Timer is a component I plan to use for other pages for the same logic but some variations on the page.